# Counting integral points in a rank-2 lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^n, n \geq 2$ be a lattice of rank 2. It is well-known (see for example Lemma 4.5 in [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783034601283)) that

$$\displaystyle \#\{\mathbf{x} \in \Lambda : \mathbf{x} \text{ is primitive, } \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert \leq R\} \ll_n \frac{R^2}{\det(\Lambda)} + O(1).$$

Recall that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ is primitive if it is not of the form $r \cdot \mathbf{y}$ for $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}, r \geq 2$.

My question is a refinement where one bounds the components of $\mathbf{x}$ individually. Suppose that (with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$) the components of $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)^T$ are bounded by $|x_i| \leq R_i$. Can we expect a bound of the shape

$$\displaystyle O_n \left(\frac{(R_1 \cdots R_n)^{2/n}}{\det(\Lambda)} + O(1) \right)?$$

Interestingly enough, such a result is possible for ternary quadratic forms. I would be interested if the above holds for $n = 3$ for lattices.

Comment: I don't think that your first display is correct. Let $\Lambda$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $(1,0,0,\dotsc)^T$ and $(0,R^2,0,\dotsc)^T$. Then the LHS exceeds $R$, while the RHS is bounded.

Comment: @GHfromMO sorry, I forgot to add the condition that $\mathbf{x}$ is primitive. I will fix that

Comment: The bound you expect (second display) is too strong. Let $\Lambda$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $(1,0,0,\dots)^T$ and $(0,1,0,\dotsc)^T$. Let $R_1=R_2=R>1$ and $R_3=1$. Then the LHS is $\gg R^2$, while the RHS is $\ll R^{4/3}$.